# print the toast when any team reaches 30 points

Tags: java, android

i create the basketball scorecard app.i want to add a functionality i.e which team reaches the 30 points first wins the game(toast message that team A wins) and if we click on point buttons it should not increase the points.

Thank you for the help.
My Code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int scoreTeamA = 0;
    int scoreTeamB = 0;
    int foul_b = 0;
    int foul_a = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(scoreTeamA>30||scoreTeamA==30)
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"team A wins",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }


    public void displayForTeamA(int score) {
        TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.team_a_score);
        scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(score));
    }


    public void displayForTeamB(int score) {
        TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.team_b_score);
        scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(score));
    }

    public void displayFiveForTeamA (View v){
        scoreTeamA = scoreTeamA + 5;
        displayForTeamA(scoreTeamA);
         
    }


    public void displayThreeForTeamA(View v) {
        scoreTeamA = scoreTeamA + 3;
        displayForTeamA(scoreTeamA);
      
    }

    public void displayFoulForTeamA(View v) {
        foul_a = foul_a + 1;
        String sA = "Total Foul : " + foul_a;
        scoreTeamA = scoreTeamA - 1;
        displayForTeamA(scoreTeamA);
        foulA(sA);
    }

    public void foulA(String f) {
        TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.foul_a);
        scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(f));
    }


    public void displayFiveForTeamB(View v) {
        scoreTeamB = scoreTeamB + 5;
        displayForTeamB(scoreTeamB);
    }

    public void displayThreeForTeamB(View v) {
        scoreTeamB = scoreTeamB + 3;
        displayForTeamB(scoreTeamB);
    }

    public void displayFoulForTeamB(View v) {
        foul_b = foul_b + 1;
        String sB = "Total Foul : " + foul_b;
        scoreTeamB = scoreTeamB - 1;
        displayForTeamB(scoreTeamB);
        foulB(sB);
    }

    public void foulB(String foul) {
        TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.foul_b);
        scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(foul));
    }

    public void resetScore(View v) {
        scoreTeamB = 0;
        scoreTeamA = 0;
        foul_b = 0;
        foul_a = 0;
        String s = "Total Foul : " + 0;
        displayForTeamA(scoreTeamA);
        displayForTeamB(scoreTeamB);
        foulA(s);
        foulB(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Don't you want to shorten `if(scoreTeamA>30||scoreTeamA==30)` to `if(scoreTeamA >= 30)`???  2) What "event" is triggering a change in score?  Don't you want to display your toast in response to that event, instead of in "onCreate()???

Comment: @paulsm4 sir it was a mistake .i print the **if(scoreTeamA>30||scoreTeam<34)** in my original code inside the **displayFiveForTeamA, displayThreeForTeamA ** methods and it print the toast when the score reaches between 30 and 34 but the score is still increases how to stop score from increases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
public void displayForTeamA(int score) {
            TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.team_a_score);
            scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(score));
        }
```

to

```
    public void displayFiveForTeamA (View v){
            if(scoreTeamA < 30){
                scoreTeamA = scoreTeamA + 5;
                displayForTeamA(scoreTeamA);
            }
        }
```

Add this if condition to your other score increasing methods, What you're missing is that you're increasing the score every time you call the method, before you add the score you need check if its already equal to 30 or greater than it.